# How to find all the possible permutations of a matrix in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, permutation

I have a matrix, for example, 5x5.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   22   -2   -2   -2    2
[2,]   -2   22    2    2    2
[3,]   -2    2   22    2    2
[4,]   -2    2    2   22    2
[5,]    2    2    2    2   22.
```

As you can see, the matrix is symmetric.
Above the main diagonal, there are 4+3+2+1=10 positions, and I find via `combn` all the possible (permutation) matrices, which have (-2) 3 times in these 10 positions. That means 10!/3!*7!=120 matrices.

But some of them are equivalent.

So,my problem is how to find the non-equivalent matrices from the 120.

I am taking about permutation matrices, because if I pick one of the 120 matrices and I use `rmperm`, I have as a result one (random) of the 120 matrices.

When I have 5x5 and 6x6 matrices, I don't have problem, because I have developed an algorithm. But now I want to do the same in a 7x7 matrix and more, but the algorithm is very slow, because I have lots of loops.

So, I want with one command, when I pick a matrix from the 120 matrices, to give me ALL the permutations matrices from the 120.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If, as josilber says, you're looking for all row and column permutations, that's n!^2. For a 10x10 matrix, that's over 13 **trillion** matrices, which is probably too many to create first and then pick out the unique ones. Is there any symmetry or structure you can use to shrink the problem?

Comment: Gregor, the matrices which I use are symmetric.

Comment: Is it always true that you have just 2 numbers (-2 and 2 in the example above) in the off-diagonal positions? If, for instance, you had the numbers 1 through 10 in those 10 positions there would be 10! permutations of them, all of which would be unique. The only reason you're able to say there are just 120 permutations (not necessarily all unique) in the example above is because you have assumed there are just two unique values, split 7/3.

Comment: Exactly josilber! It is always true that I have just 2 numbers (2 and -2) in the off-diagonal positions!

Comment: Basically what you want is permutation of multiset. The package `iterpc` will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want is permutation of multiset. The package iterpc will do the job.

```
> library(iterpc)
> I <- iterpc(c(3,7), ordered=TRUE)
> getlength(I)
[1] 120
> getall(I)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
  [1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
  [2,]    1    1    2    1    2    2    2    2    2     2
  [3,]    1    1    2    2    1    2    2    2    2     2
  [4,]    1    1    2    2    2    1    2    2    2     2
  [5,]    1    1    2    2    2    2    1    2    2     2
  [6,]    1    1    2    2    2    2    2    1    2     2
  [7,]    1    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    1     2
  [8,]    1    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     1
  [9,]    1    2    1    1    2    2    2    2    2     2
 [10,]    1    2    1    2    1    2    2    2    2     2
 [11,]    1    2    1    2    2    1    2    2    2     2
 [12,]    1    2    1    2    2    2    1    2    2     2
 [13,]    1    2    1    2    2    2    2    1    2     2
 [14,]    1    2    1    2    2    2    2    2    1     2
 [15,]    1    2    1    2    2    2    2    2    2     1
 [16,]    1    2    2    1    1    2    2    2    2     2
 [17,]    1    2    2    1    2    1    2    2    2     2
 [18,]    1    2    2    1    2    2    1    2    2     2
 [19,]    1    2    2    1    2    2    2    1    2     2
 [20,]    1    2    2    1    2    2    2    2    1     2
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 100 rows ]
```

Each row here is a permutations of 1 and 2. You should replace the 1's by -2.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you're asking for all row/column permutations. For an n x n matrix there are n! (n factorial) permutations of the rows and n! permutations of the columns, for a total of (n!)^2 total row/column permutations (not all of which are necessarily unique).

The first step would be to obtain a sample dataset and get the set of all permutations of the row/column indices (I'm assuming square matrices but it would be easy to extend to the non-square case):

```
# Sample dataset:
library(sna)
set.seed(100)
(g <- rgraph(3))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    1
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    1    1    0

# All permutations of indices
library(gtools)
(perms <- permutations(nrow(g), nrow(g)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    3    2
# [3,]    2    1    3
# [4,]    2    3    1
# [5,]    3    1    2
# [6,]    3    2    1
```

You can compute all pairings of the row/column orderings, which you can use to grab all possible row/column permutations:

```
pairings <- expand.grid(1:nrow(perms), 1:nrow(perms))
head(pairings)
#   Var1 Var2
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    1
# 3    3    1
# 4    4    1
# 5    5    1
# 6    6    1
all.perms <- lapply(1:nrow(pairings), function(x) g[perms[pairings[x,1],], perms[pairings[x,2],]])
head(all.perms)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    1
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    1    1    0
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    1
# [2,]    1    1    0
# [3,]    1    0    0
# ...
```

Finally, you can use `unique` to grab the elements of `all.perms` that are unique matrices:

```
all.unique.perms <- unique(perms)
length(all.unique.perms)
# [1] 18
```

Comment: Josilber, thanks a lot, but maybe I didn't explain it clearly.

Look, to my question, because I am gonna edit it!