# Generating all the transition matrices for given amount of nodes in R

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, transition, combinatorics

I'm working on an algorithm for Bayesian Networks that is supposed to find the optimal layout of edges for a set of nodes (e.g. for 3 nodes). To do this in Bayes Optimal way, I'll have to generate a list of all of the possible layouts for the graph in a form of transition matrices and check which one best fits the data (with certain node activation). These matrices have to be non-cyclic (as they are DAGs), but I have seperate function that checks for that so I'll just have to generate the possible transitions.

**Now the problem is that there doesn't seem to be a reasonable method or tool for generating all the possible transition matrices for a given amount of nodes in R.**

For example, if I want to generate all the possible layouts for 3-node network, the matrices should be returned in a list that starts something like this:

```
[1]
    0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0

[2]
    1, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0

[3]
    0, 1, 0
    0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0

...
```

Here we have 8 x 8 x 8 (= 512) different combinations and I would like to generate all of them seperately into a list.
(*Note that in the final solution, matrix number 2 would be discarded as it has a cycle 1 -> 1. I have a seperate function that checks for cycles so that part can be ignored from the proposed solution.*)

Building this with "for" loops is one option, build I'd like it to be flexible **(so that I can easily generate all of the networks for specified amount of nodes)**. I've been unable to find a decent solution to this.

I have checked some previous answers, e.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996083/13846011 , but this doesn't generate all the unique transition matrices.

Thank you for any answers and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The n x n binary matrices are in 1-1 correspondence with n*n bit numbers.
Given such a number K the corresponding matrix M has elements

```
M[i,j] = i+j*n'th bit of L (0<=i<n, 0<=j<n)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now the problem is that there doesn't seem to be a reasonable method or tool for generating all the possible transition matrices for a given amount of nodes in R.

A possible way (reasonable or not) is using [`hcube`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/combinat/topics/hcube). It's quite easy to generate a matrix where each row is one of the flattened *transition matrices*:

```
library(combinat)
n = 3
hc = hcube(rep(2, n*n), translation=-1)
```

`head(hc)` yields

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

If we want to make a list of matrices from this, we can do:

```
lm = lapply(1:nrow(hc), function(x) matrix(hc[x,], n, n))
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works! With "reasonable" I meant that I was worried about the time complexity and flexibility to different node amounts which caused problems with some of the libraries I checked out. This solution seems to best both issues. 

Edit: The only issue with this is that already a 5 node netowrk will require more system memory than my current setup allows. Is there a way to get around this with the library?

Comment: It's not possible - or at least not reasonable :-) - with `hcube` or any other method that generates all combinations in advance. I'm afraid we have to resort to an algorithm which builds an processes them one by one, not storing the to-be-discarded combinations at all.